# How can I pump lava without the Buildcraft pump?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

Buildcraft affects my fps too much, as such I'm looking for a replacement. So I need a way to pump lava without using BuildCraft.

Do you know any other mods that can pump and not kill my fps?

I've also tried the pump from extra utilities but it didn't really work the way I wanted it to.

Comment: What do you mean 'didn't work the way I wanted it to?' how did you want it to work? The endo-thermic pump from extra ultilities is the best lava pumping machine I've found.

Comment: Indeed. [The description of how it is used](http://ftbwiki.org/Ender-Thermic_Pump) is pretty straightforward. Put it atop a surface parallel to the surface of the lava and it is even able to pump through solid blocks below it. To use it outside of nether, edit ExtraUtilities.cfg. This pumps lava without the FPS hit you fear so knowing why you found it inadequate would be very helpful to those trying to provide an answer.

Comment: it would help if you included which pack you are using or which mods are available

Comment: My guess would be that the extra utilities pump don't just remove lava, but also put cobblestone in it's place. If the goal is to empty part of a lava lake, it will not help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Another great pump you can try is the [Gregtech Advanced Pump](http://ftbwiki.org/Advanced_Pump), which will remove flowing liquid along with source block, thus avoiding the massive lag caused by it.

[Learn more about this pump.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119899/advanced-pump-vs-buildcraft-pump)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a pump as good as the build craft pump so you are best sticking with that one. I know you are getting bad fps because of this so I would recommend [Optifine](http://optifine.net/home.php) it is a good mod that allows you to change lots of setting of minecraft and boost you fps. doubled fps is quite common. [Here's how to use and install the mod.](http://minecraft.wonderhowto.com/how-to/use-optifine-boost-mincrafts-visual-performance-eliminate-lag-and-speed-up-rendering-0134578/)

Comment: Optifine is only a client mod, isn't it? It will only help if the slowdown is due to graphics, and my experience with lava pumping tell me it will not change a thing, the slowdown is server side.

Comment: Theres actually a lot of different ways of removing liquid autonomously... its just the buildcraft pump is the go-to for its simplicity. Better and more optimized ways exist with a tiny bit of elbow grease.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the industrial craft basic pump to remove liquids and store it in cells/buckets. No liquid entities are generated(no work for the server). this is the most optimized and easy-to-craft way of cleaning out liquid. Although the Gregtech pump removes liquid blocks as well as source, it is MUCH harder to craft, and the liquid still needs to go through a pipe system (thus creating liquid entities)

[IC2 Pump](http://ftbwiki.org/Pump_%28IndustrialCraft_2%29)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this without any mods at all. Just fill your hotbar buckets, fill them with lava, make a dispenser and lever/button/pressure plate put your lava buckets in the dispenser activate your dispenser and, BAM! lava pump.